# Download-process.php redirecting page

Tags: php, html

Its been so long I am trying to create a webpage something like there is a link 
 ( https://www.apunkagames.biz/2014/10/call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3-game.html ) if you will visit here and if you will try to download the game then you will redirect this page ( https://www.apunkasoftware.net/download-process.php ) and now you click on download now button to go to the main website where the game is stored.

Help me to create a page like https://www.apunkasoftware.net/download-process.php for my website https://Cgamelover.com

I am really confused about how to create a page like that, When I click on download Now then It should redirect a page with name download-process.php then after the Main page where the file is being store

Comment: Please explain more clearly what it is you're trying to do and please provide some code

Answer (score 0):

I analyzed the implementation of the site, you can refer to it.

1. User open a game detail page (/xxx/call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3-game.html), then go to vlink page (/vlink/1002002335).
2. When User click the link on vlink page, the page (front-end html) will take the following form params to download-process.php

```
URL: download-process.php
Request Method: POST  
Form Params:  
 file: http://thefileslocker.com/xxx.html  
 refferere: www.xxxgames.biz  
 title: Call of Duty: xxx
```

3. The download-process page take these params, then show the actual link (from the param: file) at a moment.